# No matter what I ask my system to send, it only sends FF and FE

Tags: c, uart, xbee, microchip, dspic

I created a system that will read CANBUS data from a vehicle and transmit it wirelessly to a "base station". As of now, my code works in the sense that it sends things over the data line to the xbee and the xbee sends it to the receiving module except the only thing that it is sending is FF and FE no matter what I ask it to send. Any help is greatly appreciated.

main.c

```
/**
  Section: Included Files
*/
#include "mcc_generated_files/clock.h"
#include "mcc_generated_files/dma.h"
#include "mcc_generated_files/ecan1.h"
#include "mcc_generated_files/interrupt_manager.h"
#include "mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"
#include "mcc_generated_files/pin_manager.h"
#include "mcc_generated_files/reset.h"
#include "mcc_generated_files/reset_types.h"
#include "mcc_generated_files/system.h"
#include "mcc_generated_files/system_types.h"
#include "mcc_generated_files/traps.h"
#include "mcc_generated_files/uart1.h"
#include "mcc_generated_files/watchdog.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

void ms_delay (int N)
{
    T1CON = 0x08030;

    int delay = N * 62.5;   // 1 Milisecond => .001 / (256 * (1/16,000,000)) = 62.5
    TMR1 = 0;
    while (TMR1 < delay);
}

int main (void)
{
    PIN_MANAGER_Initialize();
    CLOCK_Initialize();
    INTERRUPT_Initialize();
    //DMA_Initialize();
    UART1_Initialize();
    ECAN1_Initialize();
    //INTERRUPT_GlobalEnable();
    while(1)
        {
        UART1_Write("A");
        ms_delay(2);
        UART1_Write("C");
        ms_delay(2);
        UART1_Write('S');
        ms_delay(2);
        }
}
/**
 End of File
*/
```

UART1.c

```
  Section: Included Files
*/
#include "uart1.h"

/**
  Section: UART1 APIs
*/

void UART1_Initialize(void)
{
/**    
     Set the UART1 module to the options selected in the user interface.
     Make sure to set LAT bit corresponding to TxPin as high before UART initialization
*/
    // STSEL 1; IREN disabled; PDSEL 8N; UARTEN enabled; RTSMD disabled; USIDL disabled; WAKE disabled; ABAUD disabled; LPBACK disabled; BRGH enabled; URXINV disabled; UEN TX_RX; 
    // Data Bits = 8; Parity = None; Stop Bits = 1;
    U1MODE = (0x8008 & ~(1<<15));  // disabling UARTEN bit
    // UTXISEL0 TX_ONE_CHAR; UTXINV disabled; OERR NO_ERROR_cleared; URXISEL RX_ONE_CHAR; UTXBRK COMPLETED; UTXEN disabled; ADDEN disabled; 
    U1STA = 0x00;
    // BaudRate = 2560.164; Frequency = 40000000 Hz; BRG 3905; 
    U1BRG = 0x19;

    U1MODEbits.UARTEN = 1;  // enabling UARTEN bit
    U1STAbits.UTXEN = 1; 
}

uint8_t UART1_Read(void)
{
    while(!(U1STAbits.URXDA == 1))
    {

    }

    if ((U1STAbits.OERR == 1))
    {
        U1STAbits.OERR = 0;
    }

    return U1RXREG;
}

void UART1_Write(uint8_t txData)
{
    while(U1STAbits.UTXBF)
    {

    }

    U1TXREG = txData;    // Write the data byte to the USART.
}

uint16_t UART1_StatusGet (void)
{
    return U1STA;
}

/*int __attribute__((__section__(".libc.write"))) write(int handle, void *buffer, unsigned int len) {
    int i;
    while(U1STAbits.TRMT == 0);  
    for (i = len; i; --i)
    {
        while(U1STAbits.TRMT == 0);
        U1TXREG = *(char*)buffer++;        
    }
    return(len);
}*/
```

Expected results: send YES from one module to another repeatedly
Actual results: Sends FF FE repretedly

Comment: What does stepping through the code in a debugger tell you?  And why is there commented out code in your post?

Comment: It doesnt give me any errors or anything when I run through it. There is commented out code because I have been trying some new things in it and I dont want to make any "permanent" changes until I know things work.

Comment: You are passing a _string_ to `UART1_Write` with `"A"`. It is [probably] writing the first byte of the _address_ of the string (which might be (e.g.) `0xFF123455`), hence the `FF`. Try (e.g.) `UART1_Write('A')` instead

Comment: even when I change it to UART1_Write('A') it still is only sending FE once even though it should be sending it continuously as well since its in a while(1) right?

Comment: youre not passing a uint8 to your write function.  put U1TXREG = 'A" hardcoded in the write function, then ='B' etc, and see if it changes like your expecting.  You can have pins swapped on your logic analyzer thats giving you framing issues, or false edges.  If U1TXREG = 'A' doesnt send the ascii value of 'A' then your HW setup is wrong, if it does send 'A' its your little test program here.

Comment: check the baudrate. I can't follow your calculation.

Comment: I will try the U1TXREG = ‘A’ as soon as I get to the lab. As far as the baud rate goes I used 40000000/(16*9600)-1

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is connect a logic probe or even a scope to the TX and RX lines so you can get a look at what you're actually sending.  You'll be able to look at bit times to see if you have the baud rate calculation correct.  Anything else you do will just be blind guessing.

Does this Microchip platform have an interrupt or DMA driven UART driver you can use instead of rolling your own?  Can you test your driver with a wired serial connection to a PC instead of an XBee (which introduces another possible failure point)?

Your `UART1_Write()` is blocking, so no need for the delay.

Make sure you configure the XBee for the correct baud rate (I'm pretty sure `ATBD=3` for 9600).  Try sending the sequence `0x01, 0x03, 0x07 0x0F, 0x1F, 0x3F, 0x7F, 0xFF`.  That generates a sequence of 1 bits followed by 0 bits, and might help troubleshoot an error in your baud rate calculation.